# Separate or split asociative objects into 2 arrays using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an object "member", it has keys and each keys has arrays of objects

```
var members = {
    'Father' : [
        {
            name: 'John Doe'
        }
    ],
    'Mother' : [
        {
            name: 'Jane Doe'
        }
    ],
    'Uncles': [
        {
            name: 'James Doe'
        },
        {
            name: 'Sam Smith'
        },
        {
            name: 'Mark Smith'
        }
    ],
    'Aunties': [
        {
            name: 'Mary Doe'
        },
        {
            name: 'Mae Smith'
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to split them into two arrays

```
var allMembers = [];
var half = Math.ceil(Object.keys(members).length / 2);
var firstHalf = Object.keys(members).splice(0, 4);
var secondHalf = Object.keys(members).splice(4);
allMembers.push(firstHalf)
allMembers.push(secondHalf)
```

But the result of `allMembers` is just this:

```
[["Father", "Mother"], ["Uncles", "Aunties"]]
```

I want to make it like this result:

```
0: [
   'Father' : [
        {
            name: 'John Doe'
        }
   ],
   'Mother': [
        {
            name: 'Jane Doe'
        }
   ]
],
1: [
   'Uncles': [
        {
            name: 'James Doe'
        },
        {
            name: 'Sam Smith'
        },
        {
            name: 'Mark Smith'
        }
    ],
    'Aunties': [
        {
            name: 'Mary Doe'
        },
        {
            name: 'Mae Smith'
        }
    ]
]
```

How can I achieve that?

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mqk6bswu/

Comment: Your desired result is invalid JavaScript; Arrays have numeric keys; you'd need two objects in an array (e.g. `[{ Fathers: [], Mothers: [] }, { Uncles: [], Aunties: [] }]`)

Comment: yes @HereticMonkey, how can I achieve like that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript split object by key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37312816/javascript-split-object-by-key)

Comment: Not really, but @adiga already answered.. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of getting keys, you could get [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) of the object and split them into 2 parts. Use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) on both arrays to get an array with two objects

```js
const members={Father:[{name:"John Doe"}],Mother:[{name:"Jane Doe"}],Uncles:[{name:"James Doe"},{name:"Sam Smith"},{name:"Mark Smith"}],Aunties:[{name:"Mary Doe"},{name:"Mae Smith"}]},
      entries = Object.entries(members),
      half = Math.ceil(entries.length / 2),
      firstHalf = entries.splice(0, half),
      secondHalf = entries, // remaining
      allMembers = [firstHalf, secondHalf].map(Object.fromEntries);

console.log(allMembers)
```

Answer (score 1):

The most straighforward way to achive `[{ Fathers: [], Mothers: [] }, { Uncles: [], Aunties: [] }]` is to map it manually. For example;

```
const result = [{Fathers: members.Fathers, Mothers: members.Mothers }, { Uncles: members.Uncles, Aunties: members.Aunties}];
```

A more advanced solution will be to use `Object.entries` and map the data dynamically.

Comment: Thanks.. I like @adiga's answer, it's more dynamic